# SQL Server finding string in Unicode HEX

Tags: sql-server-2008, unicode, hex

I need to find part of string which is stored in a varbinary field on SQL Server 2008. The data that is stored in the field is in HEX Binary.

For example the field has `0xA0000000001A000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000850000002416002F002A002000480065006C006C006F0020002A002F0007`

I can ignore the first 37 characters. When I look at this in a SQL application it reads as follows after the first 37 characters

/.*.H.e.l.l.o.*./

I know that the hex binary is stored in Unicode format.

My question is how can i search for the word 'Hello' using a SQL Statement.
I tried the following below but i do not get any results

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(max),fieldname) from tablename where fieldname like '%Hello%;
```

I would really appreciate any help that I can get

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the binary value is in a Unicode encoding, you will need to cast it to `NVARCHAR`, and also use a Unicode string literal for the search value:

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(max),fieldname) from tablename where fieldname like N'%Hello%';
```